# Spring Boot: PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer is not loading properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I've a Spring Boot application created as follows, that runs as a Java standalone process

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.abc.def.ghi"})
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication springApplication = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
    springApplication.setWebEnvironment(false);
    springApplication.run(args);
}

@Bean
public static PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer () {
    PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer = new MyConfigPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
    return propertyPlaceholderConfigurer;
}
```

I can see that `MyConfigPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` implementation is successfully loading the properties into its `Properties` member.

However, when `MyErrorHandler` is being initialized any of the `@Value` annotated members are not being loaded, even though they do exist in the `Properties` object

```
@Component
    public class MyErrorHandler {
    @Value("${max.retries}")
    private Integer maxRetries;
    @Value("${backoff.multiplier}")
    private Integer backOffMultiplier;

    public MyErrorHandler() {
        super();
        maximumRedeliveries(maxRetries);
        backOffMultiplier(backOffMultiplier);
    }
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Why you're using spring boot and auto configuration is completely off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Injection, of other beans or properties into annotated fields can occur only after the object has been instantiated because `@Autowired`, `@Inject`, `@Resource`, and `@Value` are handled by `BeanPostProcessors` . Hence, when the constructor is invoked, all such fields will **NOT** be populated. Nonetheless you can use a (private) method annotated with [`@Postcosnstruct`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-postconstruct-and-predestroy-annotations) to run post-init logic, when it's guaranteed that the injection has taken place.

Alternatively, you could also use [constructor injection](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-constructor-injection) to have spring call a dedicated constructor with appropriate parameters.

Comment: Completely forgot about this!

Comment: @DJ180 Heh, after one stops using spring for a while, it happens from time to time. The funny thing is that it's right under your eyes but you keep looking elsewhere (at least I used to...) :-). Cheers